# SSIS: Update a RecordSet passed into a VB.NET ScriptTask

Tags: ssis

What I am trying to accomplish is using this script task to continually insert into a generated RecordSet  I know how to access it in the script however I do not know how to update it after my changes to the DataTable have been made.

Code is Below:

```
    Dim EmailsToSend As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim EmailsToSendDt As New DataTable("EmailsToSend")
    Dim CurrentEmailsToSend As New DataTable
    Dim EmailsToSendRow As DataRow

    EmailsToSendDt.Columns.Add("Id", System.Type.GetType("System.Integer"))
    EmailsToSendDt.Columns.Add("EmailAddress", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    EmailsToSendDt.Columns.Add("EmailMessage", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))

    EmailsToSendRow = EmailsToSendDt.NewRow()
    EmailsToSendRow.Item("Id") = Id
    EmailsToSendRow.Item("EmailAddress") = Email
    EmailsToSendRow.Item("EmailMessage") = EmailMessage.ToString

    EmailsToSend.Fill(CurrentEmailsToSend, Dts.Variables("EmailsToSend").Value)
    EmailsToSendDt.Merge(CurrentEmailsToSend, True)
```

Basically my goal is to create a single row in a new data table.  Get the current record set, merge the results so I have my result DataTable.  Now I just need to update the ReadWriteVariable for my script.  Do not know if I have to do anything special or if I can just assign it directly to the DataTable I.E. Dts.Variables("EmailsToSend").Value = EmailsToSendDt

Thanks for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a previous answer of mine that addresses your problem:
[How can I store a dataset object into a package variable of data type object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881140/store-dataset-to-dts-variable/2881714#2881714)

The short answer is that you can do it just like you mentioned above, by setting the object typed variable's value to the data table variable in your script.

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up having to do.  Thank you for the help.