# How to access Object SSIS variable inside script task?

Tags: c#, ssis

I have SSIS variable of type **object** which holds the OLE DB result set from **OLE DB source**.

The object is **list of blogs** with each blog having attributes **title** and **description**.
How can I parse the SSIS object variable and iterate over each blog and then field?

**EDIT** :

I want to read full result set in script task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS - How to access a RecordSet variable inside a Script Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596992/ssis-how-to-access-a-recordset-variable-inside-a-script-task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// this gets the data object and sets ti to a data table
            OleDbDataAdapter A = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            A.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::SSISObjectVariableFromPackage"].Value);

            // for test data
            DataTable sourceTable = dt;

            //Now loop through databale and do your processing



//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Updated  -- possible solution to fix issue in comments but left original above as that works for most 

//try this version instead, mabye converting the SSIS variable to a C# object first, and not accessing it directly into the A.Fill may resolve your issue in the comments:

Object OBJDataTableValidFieldListFull = Dts.Variables["User::SSISObjectVariableFromPackage"].Value;

    // this gets the data object and sets ti to a data table
                OleDbDataAdapter A = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                A.Fill(dt, OBJDataTableValidFieldListFull);

                // for test data
                DataTable sourceTable = dt;

                //Now loop through databale and do your processing
```

Comment: This is working for me in first script task, when I tried to use same object variable in 2nd script task, the object rows are coming as zero. Its weird and I have not modified the SSIS object variable.

Comment: I have not seen that issue but I have also not tried to use the same object populated object twice.  Did you put it as ReadOnly  when passing to the script task?

Comment: Yess I did pass it has read only variable. I tried to read in two separate script tasks. I am able read only in one either first or second if I comment  but not both. In single package execution I have two linear script tasks.