# Convert DTS.Variables of type System.Object into a list

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task

I have an SSIS package that executes a SQL task in order to get the names of servers I need to connect to. Then, the results of that query are stored in an variable object called "servers". I then want to run another package on each server at once, so I wanted to split out the "servers" variable. However, when I do this in a C# Script Task, I keep getting the error:

Error: 0x1 at Script Task: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Here's the code to split out the servers variable:

> Error: 0x1 at Script Task: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

```
public void Main()
{
    var serverlist = (string[])Dts.Variables["User::servers"].Value;

    Dts.Variables["server1"].Value = serverlist[0];
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

It should be a pretty simple code, but for some reason, it just does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned that:

> I have an SSIS package that executes a SQL task in order to get the names of servers

The main problem is in the following line:

```
var serverlist = (string[])Dts.Variables["User::servers"].Value;
```

Execute SQL Task doesn't return a list of string, it return a record-set object. In order to read it within a script task you have to follow the following post *(You have to use OledbAdapter)*:

- [SSIS - How to access a RecordSet variable inside a Script Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596992/ssis-how-to-access-a-recordset-variable-inside-a-script-task)

Answer (score 1):

From the title of your question, it looks like you're trying to populate a C# list from an SSIS object variable.  If this is correct it can be done as follows.  Either you can populate a `DataTable` object with the contents of the SSIS object variable, or if you are looking to use a list specifically a list can be populated from the `DataTable` and you can then work with the list after this.  In the example below an `OleDBDataAdapter` is used to populate a `DataTable` object from the SSIS object variable using the `Fill` method.  The data filled from the object variable can they be accessed through the `DataRow` objects in the `DataTable`.  Since it looks like the SSIS object variable only contains a single column it can be accessed from column index 0 of each `DataRow`, `dr[0]` below.  You've likely already done this, but be sure that the SSIS object variable is in the `ReadOnlyVariables` field of the Script Task.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;


List<string> serverNamesList = new List<string>();

OleDbDataAdapter dtAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable serverNamesDataTable = new DataTable();

//populate data table
dtAdapter.Fill(serverNamesDataTable, Dts.Variables["User::ObjectVariable"].Value);

foreach (DataRow dr in serverNamesDataTable.Rows)
{
    //either access server names from column index 0 of DataRow or add to list
    serverNamesList.Add(dr[0].ToString()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new package variable and call it `ConnectionStringOle`
2. Add a ForEach Loop
3. **Type:** Foreach ADO Enumerator
4. **ADO object source variable:** Select the ObjectRs.
5. **Enumerator Mode:** Rows in all the tables (ADO.NET dataset only)
6. In Variable Mappings, map result to the new package variable from step 1
7. Modify the SQL server Connection Manager to set the `ConnectionString` property to the `ConnectionStringOle` value.

From there, do whatever you need to do per loop iteration.

Note: if you are only pulling the server instance's name, then you should create another package variable that parses the instance's name into the entire `ConnectionString` value. You can get this by copying the existing ConnectionString's value into the variable expression.

Comment: So, in an effort to reduce execution time, I'm trying to execute multiple packages at the same time. Since the packages that will be executed are SQL Queries, they can start unique queries on each server. Do loops wait for a package to complete or do they continue? I was originally doing that method that you suggested, but there was a need to execute SQL statements across each server simultaneously.

Comment: @GoodVibrations Since the server instance name is what governs the loop, then you will be performing one transaction on each server individually in sequential order - they will not be concurrent. If you need to execute queries on each server concurrently then a loop won't work because that is what is setting the single connection manager. Question, if you are needing package to execute simultaneously, is there the potential for a race condition?

Comment: I've never done a race condition before. What is that? If it helps to execute packages simultaneously, I'll try it.

Comment: @GoodVibrations Race conditions are not a good thing, they are a bad thing. https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/race-condition