# I have two Foreach Loop,which hava same enumerated values.So how do I deal with it?

Tags: ssis, foreach-loop-container, execute-sql-task

I declare two variables as "Object" named a and b,
and have a simple SQL task:.

```sql
select code from code_list
```

**Using Full result set, I'm trying to pass the result to the variables declared(a and b)**,

and use them(a and b) on Script Task with **two different foreach loops**。But it didn't work.

Script Task: insert the result into two different tables(A and B).

Comment: Nothing you are trying to do makes any sense

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 variables of type Object, only use one as ResultSet. Then Add a Script Task, and select 3 variables as Read/Write Variables.

Inside the Script Task, Create two DataTable variables, and Fill one table with the ResultSet variable:

- [SSIS - How to access a RecordSet variable inside a Script Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596992/ssis-how-to-access-a-recordset-variable-inside-a-script-task)

Then Copy the first DataTable into the second DataTable Variable using `dataTable1.Copy()` method

At the end, assign each DataTable to one package Variable.